# i dont know why i am getting undefined in console #javascript trying to create calculator of newton's first equation

Tags: javascript

```js
var a;
var v;
var t;
var s;
var u;

function equation1v(u, a, t) {
    var result1v = u + a * t;
    return result1v;
}

function equation1u(v, a, t) {
    var result1u = v - a * t;
    return result1u;
}

function equation1a(v, u, t) {
    var result1a = v / t - u / t;
    return result1a;
}

function equation1t(v, u, a) {
    var result1t = v / a - u / a;
    return result1t;
}


function fullequation1(v, u, a, t) {
    if (v == "undefined") {
        return "value of v is " + equation1v(u, a, t);
    } else if (u == "undefined") {
        return "value of u is " + equation1u(v, a, t);
    } else if (a == "undefined") {
        return "value of a is " + equation1a(v, u, t);
    } else if (t == "undefined") {
        return "value of t is " + equation1t(v, u, a);
    }
}

console.log(fullequation1(3, 4, 5, ));
```

why i am getting undefined in my code the last line conatains console.log but it is showing undefined instead of the desired result , i am trying to create a code that is able to solve firdt equation of motion i.e v= u+at

Comment: `"undefined"` is a string ... and undefined `variable == undefined` not `== "undefined"` ... try adding `typeof` before `v`, `u`  etc in your if's - e.g. `if (typeof v == "undefined")` - alternatively  test `if (v == undefined)`

Comment: in short, the reason you get undefined is because none of those conditions are true

Comment: try `console.log("undefined" === undefined)` you will see they arent the same

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass

```
console.log(fullequation1(1,2,3,null))
```

instead of leaving it blank.

Leaving it blank is a bad programming practice, if anything is `undefined` on purpose, it should be set to they keyword `null` instead.

Also,

once, you change it to `null`, the if conditions should check for `null` instead of `undefined`.

Do not use the string `"undefined"`, use the keyword `undefined`